# integration of complicated function with heaviside in denominator in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, numerical-integration

I want to evaluate the following expression:

[image: expression]

I have used the Matlab `int` command, but for unknown reason, complex number and pi are parts of Matlab's answer.

```
syms x;
q = int(1/((9*(1 - x^2)^(1/2)*(heaviside(x - 1) - heaviside(x + 1)))/5 + 2*(4 - x^2)^(1/2)),-2,2)
```

It is giving me this pretty complex answer:

```
(68*pi)/19 - (450*pi*957^(1/2))/6061 - (957^(1/2)*log(5700)*225*i)/6061 + (957^(1/2)log(3^(1/2)((19*319^(1/2))/2700 - (3*19^(1/2))/100 + (6061^(1/2)*i)/300 + (19*i)/300))*225*i)/6061 - (957^(1/2)log(-3^(1/2)((3*19^(1/2))/100 + (19*319^(1/2))/2700 + (6061^(1/2)*i)/300 - (19*i)/300))*225*i)/6061 + (957^(1/2)*log(10*57^(1/2))*450*i)/6061 - (19^(1/2)*243^(1/2)*6061^(1/2)*log((3^(1/2)*i + (19^(1/2)243^(1/2)(6061^(1/2)/19 + 4))/243)/(6061^(1/2)/19 + 1))*25*i)/115159 + (19^(1/2)*243^(1/2)*6061^(1/2)*log(-(3^(1/2)*i - (19^(1/2)243^(1/2)(6061^(1/2)/19 - 4))/243)/(6061^(1/2)/19 - 1))*25*i)/115159
```

where as the answer should be between 1 and 10 real only (not complex) if my research model is right.

Can you give me any suggestions, any command, or point anything I am doing wrong in matlab that is giving this complex answer.

Comment: as a side note , I have also asked this question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107164/integration-of-complicated-function-with-heaviside-in-denominator-in-matlab   I was suggested to post here too

Comment: show us the code where you define the function and where you call the `int` command, may be your function is not well defined.

Comment: Yes you were suggested to post here and I quote: "_You should work harder to ask clear questions in the future. Also, for Matlab questions, you might try StackOverflow.com/Matlab, but be sure to ask clearly and **provide code**._". But apparently you simply copy/pasted your question.

Comment: @Hoki syms x; q = int(1/((9*(1 - x^2)^(1/2)*(heaviside(x - 1) - heaviside(x + 1)))/5 + 2*(4 - x^2)^(1/2)),-2,2)

Answer (score 1):

You are worrying about the wrong thing. The result you are getting **is** in the range [1 10]. The complex parts will cancel each others out.

If I evaluate your code:

```
syms x;
q = int(1/((9*(1 - x^2)^(1/2)*(heaviside(x - 1) - heaviside(x + 1)))/5 + 2*(4 - x^2)^(1/2)),-2,2)
```

I obtain a different expression for `q` than you:

```
q =
(68*pi)/19 - (45*pi*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2))/6061 - (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(243*19^(1/2)*319^(1/2) - 4617))/6061 + (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(243*19^(1/2)*319^(1/2) + 4617))/6061 - (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(300*19^(1/2)*319^(1/2) - 5700))/6061 + (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(300*19^(1/2)*319^(1/2) + 5700))/6061 + (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(19*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2) - 19*19^(1/2)*300^(1/2)))/6061 - (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(19*19^(1/2)*300^(1/2) + 19*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)))/6061 - (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(- 76*19^(1/2)*243^(1/2) - 19*243^(1/2)*319^(1/2) - 4617*3^(1/2)*i))/12122 + (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(19*243^(1/2)*319^(1/2) - 76*19^(1/2)*243^(1/2) - 4617*3^(1/2)*i))/12122 + (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(76*19^(1/2)*243^(1/2) - 19*243^(1/2)*319^(1/2) + 4617*3^(1/2)*i))/12122 - (45*300^(1/2)*319^(1/2)*i*log(76*19^(1/2)*243^(1/2) + 19*243^(1/2)*319^(1/2) + 4617*3^(1/2)*i))/12122
```

However, if I evaluate it in an old fashion (this works on Matlab R2009a):

```
>> q.eval
ans =
  1.883829527329203 - 0.000000000000004i
```

You should notice that the imaginary part is next to nothing. This is just a residue of calculation error. You cannot expect more than 15 digits precision when using 64 bits floating point number representation (matlab `double` format). Expect even less if it is the result of long calculations (the error may grow with the number of computations).

In this case, you can safely discard a value of `0.000000000000004` and assimilate it to `0`. Which means that your integral evaluated a *real* number.

Now I don't know what your research conclude, but if you are positively certain that the result **has** to be *real*, then you can take only the *real* part of the expression:

```
>> q.real.eval
ans =
   1.883829527329203
```

---

Thanks to Horchler's comment, a better way to evaluate the value of the integral is to directly cast it into a `double` precision number :

```
>> double(q)
ans =
  1.883829527329202 - 0.000000000000000i
```

Apparently, Matlab have improved the conversion to double (and let the old `q.eval` method get deprecated) because the residual error on the imaginary part is smaller yet.

If as above you only want the *real* part of the result, use the function `real` in conjunction with `double`, which still give the same result:

```
>> double(real(q))
ans =
   1.883829527329202
```

Comment: The memory width, 32-bit or 64-bit, of your computer is *completely* immaterial to this. Please edit that out. IEEE double precision is calculated the same regardless (even on 8-bit microcontrollers). Also, `q.eval` and `q.real.eval` appear to be either old or incorrect syntax. They don't work on R2014b. `double(q)` and `double(real(q))` would work.

Comment: Also, if you use `vpa` instead of `double` to to evaluate the expression numerically in variable precision, you'll see that the imaginary component vanishes if the value of `digits` is set sufficiently high, e.g., 64.

Comment: @horchler. Thanks for the correction. It turns out `vpa` wasn't even necessary, the casting to double was enough to get rid of the trailing error. My comment about the 32/64 bit referred to the fact that the literal expressions were different  (mine is about twice as long as his) so it was just a guess to explain that (not the rounding error on `double` numbers). But you are right, it was more confusing that constructive (and only a guess even) so that's it removed.

Comment: I'd guess that the difference is due to you using an older matlab version maybe. You might indicate which `version` of Matlab you're using. And are you using Maple by chance? What does `symengine` return?

Comment: There is still residual imaginary part, it just isn't enough to show up with the active display settings.

Comment: @horchler I added the Matlab version in the edit: Matlab R2009a. `symengine` shows `MuPAD` by default (and ask me for a location for `Mapple`, which I don't have, if I try to change that).

Comment: @BenVoigt, arrrgggh. You're killing me. It shows that I'd better stick to answer subjects I have a good grip on (I use `format long` though). _That said, both of you feel free to edit as will, I trust the quality of your answers already._

Comment: @Hoki: Done.  I think the reason the imaginary part shows as 0.000...0 is that MATLAB is using the same display format for real and imaginary.  Consider http://pastebin.com/uYv5WL84 `x(4)` has no residual imaginary part at all, while `x(5)` has one that shows as 0.00000

Comment: @BenVoigt. Thanks. Interesting (and educative) example. I love to learn every day. I also tried `5+0i` just to see if that would trigger the imaginary part display but no, I just got a real part out (same than the x(4)).